# How To Integrate Odoo to Fingerprint (Fingerspot)

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

expert

I got task to make odoo (in this case odoo v10) integrate to fingerprint (in thiscase Fingerspot).

Could anyone please help me to do this?

is there any tutorial / reference for me to try this case ?

I would be happy for every answer for this question and i would be very apreciate if there is addons created for this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQ6W3S3bV5o if helps you. This is odoo plugin for integration the biometric machine without the desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this model :
[Biometric Machine[Zkteco]
by OnGood, Pravitha V](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/hr_zkteco_machine/)